# dynamic axios function by parsing object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios

Im trying to build a reusable axios function for my NodeJS project, by parsing an object, so i can in series, place multiple requests, but also use the result of the data in following requests.

Previously i had hardcoded and chained axios requests, but i need a more dynamic solution as the app grows. My two axios functions (simplied to input/output):

```
@function getTitle(params)
@param Object
@returns Response Object

@function getDescription(params)
@param Object
@returns Response Object
```

So i have two basic async functions that returns the axios requests.
Now i need a function that takes the following input:

```js
let input = {
    title: {
        name: "getTitle",
        input: {
            "keyword": "initial",
            "option": "second"
        },
        output: "getTitle.text"
    },
    description: {
        name: "getDescription",
        input: {
            "title": "getTitle.title"
        },
        output: "getDescription.text"
    }
}
```

To describe what my function will do with the input object, is we loop each key (title, description), will use the **name** value string and reference our existing function using `new Function`, and then use the input object as the parameters.

But this is where im stuck, i need to also loop the **input** objects values, in dot notation, to reference a previous call. The end result of this function is to produce a result like this:

```js
{
    "title": "This is a title",
    "description": "this is a description"
}
```

So where im lost im not sure how to write this function, I've attempted this a few times now, and im not sure if the results should be stored in a separate object, so the rest of the objects can reference it.

Has anyone else tried something similar, and how would you write this function?

Thanks

Comment: Callback/Promises would be the solution, I'd await the calls one by one. As for the function, slight adjustments check out https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_async.asp. Try to avoid callback hell, where you have callbacks nested within each other, can make code confusing to read.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i do need this to be a dynamic parsing function for my use case though, i really only want to write out my functions once, and then let the objects take over so i can send that to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily after two weeks, I've come back to the problem.
Turns out i did need to store the data in a seperate object `let newObj = {}`.

And loop over the input objects, and use a function to check for dot notation, (which can cherry pick either newObj or newOutput aslong as its the second item in the object -> then assigning those key/values to a different object `let newOutput = {}`.

Once I've looped over each, the function returns the newOutput object in the format of the input object.